# Organizing Object based on key name - Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Looking for a way to take this object

```
var config = {
    "F2-1_largerLegal-input": "F2-1_largerLegal-input",
    "F2-1_copy-font": "Ultra",
    "F2-3_copy-fontSize": "12",
    "F2-1_copy-input": "F2-1_copy-input",
    "F2-1_frameLegal-input": "Ultra",
    "F2-1_frameLegal-fontSize": "14",
    "F2-2_copy-input": "F2-2_copy-input",
    "F2-3_copy-input": "F2-3_copy-input",
    "F2-3_copy-font": "Medium",
    "F2-1_copy-fontSize": "10",
    "F2-1_product-src": "250/50/F2-1_product.png",
    "F2-2_copy-font": "Medium",
    "F2-2_copy-fontSize": "11",
    "F2-1_largerLegal-fontSize": "13"
};
```

and convert it to an object structure like the below using 'underscore.js'.

```
var config = {
    "F2":{
        "copy":{
            "F2-1_copy-input": "F2-1_copy-input",
            "F2-1_copy-font": "Ultra",
            "F2-3_copy-fontSize": "12",
            "F2-2_copy-input": "F2-2_copy-input",
            "F2-3_copy-input": "F2-3_copy-input",
            "F2-3_copy-font": "Medium",
            "F2-1_copy-fontSize": "10",
            "F2-2_copy-font": "Medium",
            "F2-2_copy-fontSize": "11"
        },
        "frameLegal": {
            "F2-1_frameLegal-input": "Ultra",
            "F2-1_frameLegal-fontSize": "14"
        },
        "largerLegal":{
            "F2-1_largerLegal-input": "F2-1_largerLegal-input",
            "F2-1_largerLegal-fontSize": "13"
        }
        "src": {
            "F2-1_product-src": "250/50/F2-1_product.png",
        }
    }
};
```

Are their best practices for looping an object and returning an object? Whenever I try the value of the object is empty.

Comment: *"Whenever I try the value of the object"*  with what code , none is shown. Would also be helpful to identify if anything is known about the structure of the property names such as ..."they always start with `Fxx-`"

Comment: Can you code a string transforming function that takes a key like `'F2-1_copy-input'`, and produces a lineage of keys like `['F2', 'copy']` ?  I'm guessing you can.  Maybe start with that?  (also note, that the input of `'F2-1_product-src'` should probably produce  `['F2', 'product']` to be consistent with what appears to be the rule.

Comment: Lodash (and maybe underscore?) has a `_.set` function that takes a dot delimited key path.  Your array from the key parsing function joined with dots will be just what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making use of `reduce` function of JavaScript. It will do the trick for you.

```js
var config = { "F2-1_largerLegal-input": "F2-1_largerLegal-input", "F2-1_copy-font": "Ultra", "F2-3_copy-fontSize": "12", "F2-1_copy-input": "F2-1_copy-input", "F2-1_frameLegal-input": "Ultra", "F2-1_frameLegal-fontSize": "14", "F2-2_copy-input": "F2-2_copy-input", "F2-3_copy-input": "F2-3_copy-input", "F2-3_copy-font": "Medium", "F2-1_copy-fontSize": "10", "F2-1_product-src": "250/50/F2-1_product.png", "F2-2_copy-font": "Medium", "F2-2_copy-fontSize": "11", "F2-1_largerLegal-fontSize": "13"};

result = Object.entries(config).reduce((acc, [key, value])=>{
   const [keyInput] = key.split("-");
   const [nestedKey] = key.split("_")[1].split('-');
   acc[keyInput] = acc[keyInput] || {};
   acc[keyInput][nestedKey] = acc[keyInput][nestedKey] || {};
   acc[keyInput][nestedKey] = Object.assign(acc[keyInput][nestedKey], {[key]:value});
   return acc;
},{});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: this is beyond awesome! Thank you for sharing, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thought I would need underscore in order to create something like this but you prooved me wrong haha

Comment: Hey @gorak, what if all the config keys were different and you just needed the F2 and not the other data?
`
var config = {
 "otherData": "otherData1",
 "otherData3": "otherData3",
 "F2-1_largerLegal-input": "F2-1_largerLegal-input",
 "F2-3_copy-fontSize": "12",
 "F2-1_copy-input": "F2-1_copy-input",
 "F2-1_frameLegal-input": "Ultra",
};`

Comment: @JohnParrott you can put condition on `keyInput` if it is f2 then further operation would take place.